# How to make responsive page like this?

Tags: html, css

Pretty straight forward.

When I zoom in on my page, the divs and such don't expand to fit the document but on the original website i'm imitating it does.  How does their code differ? What code are they using to do the trick.

Mine: http://socialvender.com/danielbrown

Theirs: http://gunbi.net/

Just hold CTRL and Zoom In.

Can someone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container" />
      <div class = "banner" />

            <h4>Gundi!</h4>
          <div id = "divider-p">
              <div class = "seperators"><span></span></div>
              <div id = "networks">
                  <!-- <div id = "facebook"><img src = "images/fb.svg" width = "24"></div>
                  <div id = "twitter"><img src = "images/twitter.svg" width = "24"></div>
                  <div id = "tumblr"><img src = "images/tumblr.svg" width = "24"></div> -->
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "navigation">
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a>
                      Home
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a>
                      Ranking
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a>
                      Support
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a>
                      Media
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a>
                      Store
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a>
                      Forum
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    <div id = "players-online">
          <div class = "amount">
              <span>0 people are playing | server online</span>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-8 content">
        <section id = "register">
          <div class = "game">
              <button id = "game-start" class = "col-2">Game Start</button>
              <!-- <br><button id = "download" class = "blue">Download</button>
              <button id = "register" class = "blue">Register</button> -->
          </div>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Full Code Here: https://jsfiddle.net/yayyjL14/

Comment: I don't see `media queries` in your CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Mm I understand, I thought he was doing it without MQ.

Comment: You could try to use vw and vh, instead px and %

Comment: the example page use boostrap, so you have a couple of options, you can use media querys (css who change the style of your page for specific size, for example mobil size) or you can use boostrap or fundation ( fundation is less know it, but more tiny that boostrap) i think the fastest and easiest way to do is using boostrap

Comment: Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your site:

One, the navbar is not responsive because you haven't put it in a responsive container, as there is no fluid measurement (i.e.: percentages) for the width. I would recommend learning Bootstrap, a CSS/Javascript framework.  Just the grid system alone (built on CSS) , would enable you to save a considerable amount of time building responsive containers that allow you to dynamically size your content depending on the size of the browser. You can download Bootstrap at: http://getbootstrap.com/ and learn the grid from: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Another problem I see is that there is no width assigned to the button, and thus  it is prone to changing width. I would set the width to a px, just so it does not resize, and stays a certain width, as there as no point on a mobile device to have a button that is too small (generally stays the same size on both desktop and mobile, although you may alter this via media queries).

Comment: I think your assuming that he is using bootstrap I don't see anywhere where he links to bootstraps css js or anything else related to boostrap in his version of the page

Comment: Altered my answer to fit his question.